# Why is my foot mesh moving out of place when rigging?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

Every time I try to move my foot bone it just moves totally out of place.
I don't get it. It seems like everything is done right.

Bones:

Thigh Leg : Child of Body/Head Bone.

Low Leg : Child of Thigh Bone.

Foot : Child of Nothing.

Toes : Child of Foot.

Low Leg IK Constraint : Target = Foot. Pole Target = Knee IK
                        Pole Angle = -90 & Chain Length = 2.  Everything else default.

Low Leg IK: X = Unlocked / Limited  /  0 - 180
            Y = Locked
            Z = Locked

My foot mesh is parented to my foot bone as Bone and not Automatic weights.

I just don't understand what the heck is happening?

feels like everything is done precisely.

Help would be much appreciated.

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Try aplying the location, scale and rotation, by pressing Ctrl + A

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried that but that didn't work either.

Comment: Of the mesh, not the bones

Comment: yep that's what I did.

Comment: Upload the blend then.

Comment: Alright but. lol I'm making a Mediafire account so I can upload it. it'll take a second.

Comment: Use pastall.org

Comment: Oh sorry I just made an account and uploaded it.

https://www.mediafire.com/?ori1uk2561nms4e

What's wrong with Media Fire does it suck or something?

Btw Thanks for checking this out I appreciate the help dude.

Comment: I don't know if this is normal or not but when I rotate my foot bone fully around or move foot in an odd position. It stays in that position even after I release my right click, or press Alt + R/Alt + G/Alt + S.
The only way it fixes itself is if I tab to swap between edit mode and pose mode.

Comment: Nothing wrong with MediaFire, just that pasteall doesn't require an acount

Comment: Well alrighty. I'll keep that bookmarked. But I'm also noticing that my foot mesh is moving towards my knee when I move the bone forwards. hmm..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16129/discussion-between-xeke-hu-and-someonewithpc).

Answer (score 1):

everything is fine with the rig, but the Knee IK.L (pole target) bone is the child of some bone in the IK chain. If you parent it to main bone things look much better.
If it still doesn't work, see the blend file attached ( http://www.pasteall.org/blend/41604 ).

Comment: Please use [Blend-Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) when sharing .blend files on this site. :)